# Is there a more elegant way of creating these numpy arrays?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I feel like I'm creating too much arrays and wasting resources, so I'm looking for a cleaner and more efficient approach for the following problem:

Suppose we have an oscillating graph, and we know the positions of the minimums (`min_x˛`) and maximums (`max_x`). We pick a reference point `ref_point` (around 2.35 on the figure below), and the to closest extremal values (2.25 and 2.45 on the figure) we assign 1 * PI, to the second closest extremal values we assign the value 2 * PI, and so on. This way we get the lower graph on the figure (Note that the values are offseted by -4*PI, but that's irrelevant for now).

[image: This figure helps]

Here is my solution:

```py
import numpy as np

def min_max(ref_point, min_x, max_x):

    # finding the maximum and minimum values which are smaller than reference point
    neg_max_freq = np.array([a for a in (ref_point - max_x) if a < 0])
    neg_min_freq = np.array([b for b in (ref_point - min_x) if b < 0])

    # joining them together and flipping order
    neg_freq = sorted(np.append(neg_max_freq, neg_min_freq), reverse=True)

    # finding the maximum and minimum values which are greater than reference point
    pos_max_freq = np.array([c for c in (ref_point - max_x) if c > 0])
    pos_min_freq = np.array([d for d in (ref_point - min_x) if d > 0])

    #joining them together
    pos_freq = sorted(np.append(pos_min_freq, pos_max_freq))


    pos_values = np.array([np.pi * (i+1) for i in range(len(pos_freq))])
    neg_values = np.array([np.pi * (i+1) for i in range(len(neg_freq))])

    # joining the values for the lower graph on the picture
    x_s = np.append(pos_freq, neg_freq)
    y_s = np.append(pos_values, neg_values)

    return x_s, y_s
```

Example usage:

```py
>>> min_x = np.arange(np.pi/2, 4.5*np.pi, np.pi)
>>> max_x = np.arange(0, 4*np.pi, np.pi)
>>> x, y = min_max(0, min_x, max_x)

>>> x
[ -1.57079633  -3.14159265  -4.71238898  -6.28318531  -7.85398163
  -9.42477796 -10.99557429]

>>> y
[ 3.14159265  6.28318531  9.42477796 12.56637061 15.70796327 18.84955592
 21.99114858]
```

Is there another more efficient way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1):

Here how I would change the `min_max` code without writing so many temporary variables and avoiding list comprehensions:

```
def min_max(ref_point, min_x, max_x):

    max_freq = ref_point - max_x
    min_freq = ref_point - min_x

    # Faster sort
    neg_freq = np.sort(np.append(max_freq[max_freq<0], min_freq[min_freq<0]))[::-1]
    pos_freq = np.sort(np.append(max_freq[max_freq>0], min_freq[min_freq>0]))

    pos_values = np.pi * np.arange(1, len(pos_freq)+1)
    neg_values = np.pi * np.arange(1, len(neg_freq)+1)

    x_s = np.append(pos_freq, neg_freq)
    y_s = np.append(pos_values, neg_values)

    return x_s, y_s
```

Regarding sorting performance, I tested with a random array of size 1million, here the results:

```
a = np.random.randint(0, 1000, 1_000_000)

%timeit sorted(a, reverse=True)
522 ms ± 29.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit np.sort(a)[::-1]
55.2 ms ± 958 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

numpy being 9.5x faster than vanilla python.

Comment: Note that `pos_values = np.pi * np.arange(len(pos_freq))` should be `pos_values = np.pi * np.arange(1, len(pos_freq) + 1)` and also `neg_values` too. Thank you, this seems to be a better solution.

Comment: Thank you for catching that. I will edit the solution